# How round result from expanding?

Tags: math, rounding, mathcad

I'm trying to figure out how can I'm round result after expanding function.
I have tried to change Math Formatting no result.
If anyone knows how to round expand calculating result, I'd appreciate it for help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, just write expand, float,3 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jBHU.png)